# How to have multiple *ngIf combined with && operator and as in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I achieve the 'as' with '&&' operator to get the following result?

```
*ngIf="(items$ | async as items) && (filters$ | async as filters)"
```

Currently this is returning a template parse error.
I've tried out a bunch of variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in these three ways:

1.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="filters$ | async as filters">

  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

---

2.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ items: items$ | async, filters: filter$ | async } as data">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.items && data.filters">

  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

---

3.

ts:

```
readonly filterItems$ = combineLatest([
  this.items$,
  this.filters$
]).pipe(
  map(([ items, filters ]) => ({ items, filters }))
);
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="filterItems$ | async as filterItems"></ng-container>
```

With the last option you can access the items and filters like `filteritems.items` and `filterItems.filters`

Comment: Great. Wow. Thanks Man.